# Утечка памяти ImageView

Tags: java, android

В Activity у меня 1 Fragment с ListView. В ListView фотографии. При смене вкладок в Activity , наполнение ListView(которое в Fragment'е) - меняется. Фото остаются в памяти и возникает ошибка OutOfMemory. Нужна ваша помощь, спасибо.

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private int layout;

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView mphoto;
        TextView id;
        TextView title;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mphoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mphoto);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int i) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        vView.setTag( new ViewHolder(vView) );
        return vView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context ctx, Cursor c) {
        int index_id = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.C_ID);
        int index_photo = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.C_MPHOTO);
        int index_title = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.C_TITLE);

        String string_photo = c.getString(index_photo);
        String string_id = c.getString(index_id);
        String string_title = c.getString(index_title);

        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        vh.mphoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aaa.aaaaa/drawable/" + string_photo));
        vh.id.setText(string_id);
        vh.title.setText(string_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Про какие вкладки идет речь? покажите код адаптера `ListView`

Comment: Добавил адаптер, а вкладки - TabLayout

Comment: Т.е. в каждой табе свой `ListView`? или в каждой разный? если разный, адаптеры у них одинаковые?

Comment: адаптер один и тот же, и ListView тот же, в зависимости от таба(их 8) меняются картинки в ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader . Можете настроить как Вам удобно и необходимо.